# Legends to data frames in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This plot is otherwise what I need, but there should be legends for the data frames. With `bind_rows` and `.id = "id"` the data frames are named 1 and 2, which is the order they are put in the code. How to name them manually?

[image]

The code ↓

```
bind_rows(B, C, .id = "id") %>%
  filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

The data frames ↓

```
structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L), 
    mean = c(5.22549019607843, NA, 4.95098039215686, 4.39705882352941, 
    5.47058823529412, 5.51470588235294, 4.50490196078431, 4.92647058823529, 
    4.40686274509804, 5.56862745098039, 5.56372549019608, 5.23529411764706
    ), sd = c(1.1524816893289, NA, 1.31214449357814, 1.5422430010719, 
    1.12039650223724, 1.15104553532809, 1.37714471881058, 1.34621721218454, 
    1.30030385262334, 0.871099231072865, 0.830963499839951, 1.36945187401243
    )), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mean = c(5.38461538461539, 
4.38461538461539, 4.69230769230769, 4.30769230769231, 5.15384615384615, 
5.38461538461539, 4.76923076923077, 5.30769230769231, 4.53846153846154, 
5.61538461538461, 5.69230769230769, 4.92307692307692), sd = c(1.26085034391223, 
1.44559454541846, 1.03155347127648, 1.60128153805087, 0.898717034272917, 
1.12089707663561, 1.01273936708367, 0.85485041426511, 0.967417922046845, 
1.26085034391223, 0.85485041426511, 1.84668795692624)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want the names to be object names, use a named `list` as input to `bind_rows` - which we get automatically with `dplyr::lst` (returns a named list with names being the object names itself).  By default, if there is no names, it will use the sequence

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
lst(B, C) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'id')  %>%
    filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
    theme_minimal() + 
     theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

-outut

[image]

---

Or otherwise do this manually as a named input

```
bind_rows(B = B, C = C, .id = 'id')
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. But I still have a problem with that "id" above the legends, it is unnecessary and should be removed. Do you know how to do that? I guess that requires another solution than ```.id = ```

Comment: @erinho just use the `theme` in the updated